# Problem with DWA-131

Tags: networking, virtualbox

When I plug my DWA-131 device to my Windows machine, all goes allright(the DWA-131 has its own private ip address). My situation is: I want to manage DWA-131 through my parrot VM(and not from my windows machine), to do this, I've set up an usb filter that captures DWA-131 correctly(because when I turn on the VM, DWA-131 is no longer used by my windodws machine, and the parrot machine captures the new network interface correctly: wlan...). The problem is that when I turn on the VM DWA-131 goes off instantly, and then when I turn the VM off DWA-131 goes instantly on. And of course the network interface wlan... created by DWA-131 doesn't have its own ip address.
Hope anyone can help :)

Comment: Windows and Parrot are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a pointer to the problem rather than a complete answer. I don't have a wifi dongle, and my system works the other way = I boot up Ubuntu and then run windows bridged under that.

You have two possible solutions:

- Use a bridged solution on you VM, which will allow your Parrot Ubuntu to communicate over then bridge to Windows and then via the wifi dongle. I c know how to set this up when Ubuntu is the host, but I can't tell you with Windows as the host.
- When you installed Ubuntu it almost certainly did not find a network interface, and so configured itself for working without a network. You will need to set up a netplan on Ubuntu. It is remotely possible that Ubuntu didn't load any networking, but this sounds unlikely. My netplan, which is a default universal one, is below. After loading (or editing) a netplan, you need to execute **sudo netplan apply** to activate it.

  ## Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system

  network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager